# Corregir Menu Hamburguesa Animacion

Tags: jquery, menú, animación

necesito ayuda en la animacion de mi menu hamburguesa, al momento de que el hacemos click en el menu se ejecuta bien la animacion, pero esta tambien se activa al hacer click en cualquier parte del documento ¡AYUDA!

```
<a href="https://gyazo.com/b9990a79cdfa722aa3feb6eea3e0228b">
<img src="https://i.gyazo.com/b9990a79cdfa722aa3feb6eea3e0228b.gif" 
     alt="https://gyazo.com/b9990a79cdfa722aa3feb6eea3e0228b" width="310"/></a>
```

codigo jQuery:

```
//Hamburguer Menu Animacion
  $(document).ready("#navbar").click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('activate');
});
```

Codigo Corregido:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('activate');
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Animacion Menu Hamburguesa]

Esta es la animacion, solamente quiero saber como implementarlo para que se active solo cuando se aprieta el boton.